# SQL Sumar datos repetidos de una tabla

Tags: php, sql

Tengo esta tabla llamada cupones:

```
id| numero | gastos 
---------------------
01  | 5    | 10        
02  | 8    | 50        
03  | 5    | 10
```

Necesito hacer una consulta a la base de datos con PHP para crear una tabla que muestre el gasto total de cada numero y que no se vea repetido. Así debería mostrar :

```
numero | gastos 
----------------
5    | 20        
8    | 50
```

La consulta que estoy haciendo agrupa el numero repetido en una misma fila, pero no  suma los gastos
del mismo. La estoy haciendo asi:

```
SELECT * FROM cupones GROUP BY numero
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado usando `SUM()`?

Answer (score 2):

Tal como te comentan, la solución es hacer una suma, mediante la función `SUM`, agrupando el resultado por el número.

```
SELECT numero, SUM(gastos) as gastoTotal
FROM cupones 
GROUP BY numero
```

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias!